# How to convert a function into a method that extends an existing Java class

Tags: java

I have the following simple function that returns the position of a `String` in a string array (`String[]`).

```
private int getIndexOf(String needle, String[] haystack) {
    int indexOfNeedle = -1;
    for (int index=0;index<haystack.length;index++) {
        if (haystack[index].equals(needle)) {
            indexOfNeedle = index;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert this to be a method of the ArrayList class so that I can call it with:

```
String[] myArray = {"red","green","blue"};
int indexOfGreen = myArray.getIndexOf("green");
```

(I know there are existing libraries I can include that include `indexOf` but reinventing this is a lesson for me as well.)

I believe the approach will involve `extends ArrayList` and that is it probably the class that I need to extend so my function above will need to be modified to fit into that extension class...

Rather than using `haystack` in the method version I would also expect to be able to search inside `this` referring to the array object that the method was called from.

I'm also thinking that I may need to replace my String[] arrays with this new extended class of array (or can I use an override to include my new method in the excusing String Array class?).

As I say, **this is to help me learn how to do this in general in Java so the exercise itself may seem a bit pointless** and the point of the question isn't really to learn how to find the position of an element in an array - that's just by way of an example.

Comment: An array isn't an arraylist. And you can't add methods to arrays. And this code doesn't compile anyway.

Comment: (Note: the easiest way to implement this is `Arrays.asList(haystack).indexOf(needle)`).

Comment: "I believe the approach will involve extends ArrayList" this is *almost* never the right answer. There is no harm or foul in having methods outside the class: taking the list to be searched as a parameter allows you to apply the method to *any* list, not just one of the special ones you have constructed. In other words, methods outside the class are far more reusable.

Comment: You also could create a new class and let it extend ArrayList<T> class. But as @AndyTurner said an array isn't an arraylist, eventhough it's using an array internally, maybe you should read on the differences of both.

Comment: *FYI:* `ArrayList` already has an `indexOf()` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Difference between `Array` and `ArrayList` is interesting - can't believe I missed that. Also that `indexOf()` is available for an ArrayList anyway. My general question still stands, however, about extending an existing class with additional methods (say, for example, a very specific type of sort for an ArrayList).

Comment: As you can't add methods to `array`s, is there a better example of what I am asking here. Maybe sorting an `ArrayList` (as per my last comment) would be a better example (after reading a description of the differences between the two)?

Comment: @FatMonk Why reinvent the wheel when core Java's ArrayList already has `.indexOf(Object o)` which gives you exactly the same thing?

Comment: @user3437460 Because the question IS NOT about creating an indexOf function - the question is a general question about how you go about adding new methods to existing classes. I only used `array` (and `ArrayList`) as examples as I thought they were simple enough to provide a short explanation of what I was trying to achieve. Once again - this question is not about how to add an .indexOf method to an array, it is about how you add any type of method to any already existing class.

Comment: @FatMonk I am afraid there is no way you can add methods to existing classes in Java. One work around solution is to create a new class that extends an existing class, write new methods on that newly created class.

Comment: @user3437460 I believe I suggested that in my question (2nd paragraph after the second code block, starting "I believe the approach will involve...") but I just can't seem to figure out the detail of how to do it. I'm attempting this in Android Studio and eveything I am trying is showing various warnings about things not being resolvable etc. Hence why I was looking for a simple example that used some nice simple function as per my original (now admittedly erroneous) `array` example.

Comment: @FatMonk You may consider revising your question to something like "How to add new methods to existing Java class". From what I see on the comments here, most people (unfortunately including myself) didn't completely read your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This answer is based upon the comments, which say that the question is about extension functions)*

## Java extension functions

Java does not allow extension functions, but there are alternatives you can use instead

## Alternatives

- Wrapping

  - You can have a class which contains the original object, and passes through the existing ones you want to use, while implementing the new ones
- Extension

  - You can extend the original object type, but then the instances must be of your new type, rather than the original one
  - You only need to include the new methods, the rest pass to the super type

## Other languages

Some other JVM languages, like Kotlin, do support extension functions, but Java itself does not

Comment: This second alternative is what what I was expecting, but the first alternative also looks interesting. Could you give a simple example of the syntax of each way of acheiving this? I've searched for examples but the ones I've found haven't been adding extesion methods.

Answer (score 0):

***Not a good idea.***

The best practice is to have a more general type (interface) in the declaration.

```
void f(List<String> list) { ... }
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This allows other implementations, and being used as parameter is more flexible/powerfull.

Trying to extend these all known classes/interfaces will cause artefacts like rewrapping old classes with new classes and so on.

Instead use static functions in a utility class. Like the `Collections` and `Arrays` classes. With a `binarySearch` and other goodies.

*By the way, such functionality as mentioned, probably exists, and one
would like to build upon existing general functionality, instead of reinventing
the wheel.*

```
int index = Arrays.asList(haystack).indexOf(needle);
```

Comment: I think I need to read up on Java in general a bit more to understand this answer! It all sounds like good advice, but my lack of Java experience means that that judgement doesn't count for much at this stage - back to the books I guess.

Comment: It in effect shows a good beginner's attitude: how can I extend the tool classes that we all need to use. However it worth better to search proven classes and methods, and finding the right tool. Instead of for loops and indexing, one then also encounters Set and contains.